# Suppose an array contains only two kinds of elements, how to quickly find their boundaries?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, search

I've asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70653883/how-to-quickly-search-for-a-specified-element-in-an-ordered-array-consisting-of) before, but this time it's different.

Since our array contains only two elements, we might as well set it to 1 and -1, where 1 is on the left side of the array and -1 is on the right side of the array:

```
[1,...,1,1,-1,-1,...,-1]
```

Both 1 and -1 exist at the same time and the number of 1 and -1 is not necessarily the same. Also, the numbers of 1 and -1 are both very large.

Then, define the boundary between 1 and -1 as the **index** of the -1 **closest** to 1. For example, for the following array:

```
[1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1]
```

Its boundary is 3.

**Now**, for each number in the array, I cover it with a device that you have to unlock to see the number in it.

**I want to try to unlock as few devices as possible that cover 1, because it takes much longer to see a '1' than it takes to see a '-1'. And I also want to reduce my time cost as much as possible**.

How can I search to get the boundary as quickly as possible?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question is it?

Comment: @Chris Strictly speaking it is. I mainly want to know what algorithm should be used to find the boundary as quickly as possible. This question is actually an abstraction of a specific problem, and it is because I found that for specific problem, binary search is much slower than reverse traversal, so I asked this question.

Comment: It's a math problem if we're being honest.  You might get more help from posting in math or stats stack exchange.

Comment: How do you build the list? The only way to get the boundary index faster than with `index()` would be that you hold said index in a variable and update it every time you update the list.

Comment: list is the given data, but I need to unlock the device to know which positions are 1 and which are -1.

Comment: Is the list guaranteed to be ordered? With all 1 at the beginning and all -1 at the end? In this case, a binary search is optimal.

Comment: @Stef Yes. But this question is actually an abstraction of a specific problem, and it is because I found that for specific problem, binary search is much slower than reverse traversal, so I asked this question.

Comment: *"I've asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70653883/how-to-quickly-search-for-a-specified-element-in-an-ordered-array-consisting-of) before, but this time it's different."* I've read your other question, and I cannot spot the difference. What is the difference between the two problems? It looks like you have the exact same array in both problems, and are looking to find the exact same "boundary".

Comment: @Stef Yes, it's the same array and the bounds are defined similarly. But in my previous question, 1 and -1 are directly visible. And here you can't, you have to unlock the device to see it.

Comment: What does "reverse traversal" mean? A simple traversal of the array, one element at a time? It's possible that traversing by starting at one specific end is faster, if the boundary is really really close to that end. But binary search is guaranteed O(log(n)), whereas simple traversal is Ө(n) except in a very few very specific cases.

Comment: @stef: the problem is essentially different in that the cost of the queries are asymmetric: a query returning 1 is slower. But the question is not at all about programming.

Comment: @Lancdorr What does "unlock the device" mean? Computers don't have an "overall vision" like humans do. When you have an array of numbers, a computer program will only compare the values of cells it's been explicitly asked to compare.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ooooooooh I missed that sentence. Thank you.

Comment: @Stef Sorry for my bad english. "reverse traversal" means to traverse the list from right to left.

Comment: No worries, your English is fine, it's me who didn't read the question properly.

Comment: The best solution probably depends on your assumptions about the data. If looking at "1" is 100 times more expensive than looking at "-1", and you expect that there are less than 100 "-1" in the array, you should just do your reverse traversal. If you expect that there may be 100000 "-1" in the array, then it might be best to start with a binary search, then once the search interval is small enough, finish with a reverse traversal.

Comment: I think the question can be paraphrased: there's a hidden number n, 0 <= n <= N. You can guess a number, and are told if your guess is too low, or greater-than-or-equal. Minimize the expected cost of finding the number, given that a too-low guess costs 100, and a greater-than-or-equal guess costs 1.

Comment: @Stef: to answer the question, I would assume a uniform distribution of the "side lengths".

Comment: @Stef My previous statement was somewhat vague. In fact, 100s and 1s are only used to describe, I want to avoid seeing 1 as much as possible

Comment: It's good to have parameters to describe how much you want to avoid looking at 1. A reverse traversal guarantees that you'll look at only one 1, and it's the only algorithm that guarantees that. But if you have a billion elements in your array, perhaps you would prefer to risk looking at a few 1s rather than to risk looking at a billion -1. So, the parameter "ratio cost(1) / cost(-1)" and the parameter "number of elements in array" and "what is the probability distribution" are very relevant to devise an optimal strategy.

Comment: If you want to avoid 1 "as much as possible", you have exactly (eggsactly?) the egg-dropping problem with 1 egg. If you have a fixed number of 1's you're ok with seeing, you have exactly the egg-dropping problem with that number of eggs. If you have costs for wrong and right guesses, you are in somewhat new territory.

Comment: [the egg-dropping problem being this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Egg_dropping_puzzle)

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is very like the "egg dropping" problem, but where a wrong guess has a large fixed cost (100), and a good guess has a small cost (1).

Let E(n) be the (optimal) expected cost of finding the index of the right-most 1 in an array (or finding that the array is all -1), assuming each possible position of the boundary is equally likely. Define the index of the right-most 1 to be -1 if the array is all -1.

If you choose to look at the array element at index i, then it's -1 with probability `i/(n+1)`, and 1 with probability `(n-i+1)/(n+1)`.

So if you look at array element i, your expected cost for finding the boundary is `(1+E(i)) * i/(n+1) + (100+E(n-i-1)) * (n-i+1)/(n+1)`.

Thus `E(n) = min((1+E(i)) * i/(n+1) + (100+E(n-i-1)) * (n-i+1)/(n+1), i=0..n-1)`

For each n, the `i` that minimizes the equation is the optimal array element to look at for an array of that length.

I don't think you can solve these equations analytically, but you can solve them with dynamic programming in O(n^2) time.

The solution is going to look like a very skewed binary search for large n. For smaller n, it'll be skewed so much that it will be a traversal from the right.

Answer (score 1):

If I am right, a strategy to minimize the expectation of the cost is to draw at a fraction of the interval that favors the -1 outcome, in inverse proportion of the cost. So instead of picking the middle index, take the right centile.

But this still corresponds to a logarithmic asymptotic complexity.

There is probably nothing that you can do regarding the worst case.